# Maintaining User Stories AND Use Cases

Tags: project-management, agile

As the topic states I would like to know when it is helpful to have both:

`user stories` and `use cases`

In my understanding, user stories are more abstract goals while use cases are more in detail.
(beside the notation)

So are there any benefits for maintaining them both or is it better to only choose one of them?

*(refering to an international medium to big project)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go as far as saying that having both is an anti-pattern.

In agile development we want to keep the amount of red tape and bureaucracy to a minimum - stories can be little as a sentence on a card. All the rest can be defined in-iteration, while coding, and possibly face to face.

On the other hand, a user story is synonym with deciding *ahead of time* what should be implemented. This, in agile development is doubly bad:

1. It's directive and not inclusive: stories describe *what we are trying to achieve* and use cases describe *how we decided that something generally unspecified should be achieved*.
2. It's work ahead of time and thus a risk. Not all stories are going to be implemented. Not all stories will be implemented in the way one thinks at the time of writing them.

Comment: So you are suggesting not to use stories or cases at all?

Comment: @Coretek yes, if you are doing agile, do not use them.

Comment: "If you are agile, do not use "user story or use cases". That is wrong "advice" even for Agile community.

Comment: Many guys from agile community like Alistair Cockburn, James Coplien, Craig Larman advice "Use Cases". At least they are not against to. And other agile guys Kent Beck- Mike Cohn advice user stories.I think Skliwz you confuse the concept of evolutionary requirements analysis with requirement capture-discovery styles. Both can be used also with evolutionary requirement analysis

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding me. I never said do not use user stories. I said don't use use cases if you already have stories. References: "Working software over comprehensive documentation", "Simplicity--the art of maximizing the amount of work not done--is essential.", "The most efficient and effective method of conveying information to and within a development team is face-to-face conversation.", "Business people and developers must work together daily throughout the project." --http://agilemanifesto.org/

Answer (score 1):

User stories are referring to the goal of what you want to be achieved (the need). 
A user story can be technical or functional and it can be "splitted" (described) in tasks. Tasks are technical. It's more like use cases.

In my option, you don't have to maintain use cases AND user stories because one is overlapping the other.

Answer (score 1):

From a purist standpoint, one or the other. However, based on personal past experience, combining use cases with user stories maybe advisable for teams transitioning from waterfall to agile, especially in the case of geographically dispersed teams. i.e., until team members get skilled at writing, handling and understanding user stories.

In another scenario, creating use cases could be a project delivery requirement for teams starting off on a experimental agile initiative, in a large waterfall based organization.